# Laravel route containing a period/dot (.) character

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create the following route in Laravel, which contains a dot character:

```
Route::get( '.test', 'PageController@dot_test');
```

but it keeps giving me the following error:

```
Forbidden - You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

How can I route a URL containing a dot, like the following:
http://example.com/.test

Comment: Typically `.` are used to denote filetype/domains/etc, like `www.whatever.com`, `index.php`, etc. You might have a hard time getting Laravel and your webserver to understand how to handle `.` in an unexpected place like that. I think it's allowed (i.e. no specific rules that say you can't), but unless you have a specific reason, i'd say just go with `/test`.

Answer (score -1):

When serving locally with `php artisan serve` a route defined as below will work.

```php
Route::get('/.test', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

However from the filesystem perspective the leading dot is assigned to hide files (on a linux filesystem). Therefor the majority of the webbrowsers will block any request that starts with a dot by default to offer a secure default out of the box. You'll need to allow the webserver to serve uri with a leading dot. It has the looks your error is returned by the webserver and not by the PHP process and/or your laravel application.